# Unwanted value inserted in SQL

Tags: sql

I am creating a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE page22
(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Semester varchar(20),
    GPA decimal(3,2),
    TC decimal(3,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

I am inserting data like this:

```
INSERT INTO page22 (Semester, GPA, TC)
VALUES ('1st Semester', '3.50', '21.0');
```

The problem is, when I insert this data into the database, unwanted data is inserted into the `TC` column. Here, I provided a value of `21.0`, but instead `9.99` was inserted. To get the appropriate insert, what do I need to do?

[image: See the photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value for `decimal(3,2)` is `9.99`. So when you try to insert 21.0 it takes the default max value `9.99`.

Try changing your schema from `decimal(3,2)` to `(5,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the definition of the field since `decimal(3,2)` supports a maximum value of `9.99` as said by [Vishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031209/vishal). In order to do so:

```
ALTER TABLE page22 ALTER COLUMN TC decimal(6,2)
```

The first number indicates the length of the number and the second the number of decimal spaces, so the maximum value for `decimal(6,2)` is `9999.99`